# Which database access aproach is used in CI?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have heard, (thanks to SO) that mysql_* family of functions is vulnerable to SQL injections, so it is always recommended to use **mysqli_* OR PDO approach.**

So, I tried to trace out which of these approaches is used in Codeigniter as I have been using CI since 4 months. But I could not get it out.

Can anybody tell me which of these or any other approach is used in CI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't matter which driver you use in terms of sql injection - they are all prone to it. The thing about the mysql_* family is that it's deprecated and the recommendations you got are correct. CI offers auto-protection against some forms of sql injection, but don't forget always to double-check your inputs and **ALWAYS make sure they are filtered/sanitized**, especially if you're using core db functions. The best approach there is to use prepared statements (one thing that mysql_* can't offer, from what I recall).

Comment: @Shomz : ok, now i got it clear. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses whichever method you choose, based on your `config/database.php` file. For example, if you choose `mysqli` as your driver, it will use the `mysqli` family of functions. If you choose `mysql`, it will use the `mysql` family, and so on.

There is a PDO driver, but it's not the most stable thing in the world in the current releases.

If you're using the "active record" functions in CodeIgniter (which should really be called "query builder" functions, since they don't follow the Active Record pattern), then all of your data is automatically sanitized with the appropriate functions. If you say, for example, `$this->db->where('field', $value)`, and you're using the `mysqli` driver, CodeIgniter will automatically call `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the `$value` input you pass to it, rendering the query safe.

I should also note that this automatic sanitization only applies to the active record helper functions, like `$this->db->get` and the like. If you try to run your own query using `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '" . $field . "'")` then you need to take care to protect yourself, since you're bypassing CodeIgniter's security mechanisms. Running a query directly with the `query()` method is like saying "don't worry, I know what I'm doing." You need to specifically ask CodeIgniter to sanitize certain values for you by calling `$this->db->escape()` or its related functions. If you just concatenate variables into your query, then you're going to open yourself up to SQL injections.

Comment: I didnt find any configuration related to database in config.php, so, it must be using Active  Record pattern, but is it safe from sql injections ?

Comment: @SujitSingh Sorry, I misspoke. Database stuff has it's own config file, in `application/config/database.php`. The value for the `driver` key is the one that chooses which database driver (mysql, mysqli, postgres, etc.) is used.

Comment: @AgentConundrium : yes, i found $active_record = TRUE; in database.php; so it is confirmed that it uses Active Record. My last question is , is it safe from sql injections? as safe as others ?

Comment: @SujitSingh If you use the active record stuff (for example, `$this->db->where('field', $value);`, then it's safe because CI will take care of the escaping for you. If you specify your own queries, such as `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '" . $value . "'");` then all bets are off, since you're bypassing CI's safety mechanisms.